# Setting static file in elastic beanstalk

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Trying to have django look for static files in the right directory, when hosting with elastic beanstalk.

Config file:

```
option_settings:    
 "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
    "/static/": "static"
```

Getting error message:

> ERROR   Invalid option specification (Namespace: 'aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles', OptionName: '/static/'): Unknown configuration setting.

Tried following code from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html) as a test.

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: production.settings
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml
    /images: staticimages
```

Getting the same 'unknown configuration settings' error.

Comment: I tried, both. But I will edit to clear the confusion. Thanks

Comment: To clarify, I asked to check without quotation marks and slash. Then I removed the comment when I released it could be AMI version issue.

Comment: What did you decide to do in the end?  Do you use Amazon Linux AMI that does support it?

Comment: Exactly, using linux one for now will update later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using Amazon Linux 2? If yes, then it does not support the `aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles`.

From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-namespaces):

> Configuring static files using the
>   aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles namespace is **only
>   supported on Amazon Linux AMI Python platform versions**

Comment: @Lev No problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer for Amazon Linux 2 is to change:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml
    /images: staticimages
```

to

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:proxy:staticfiles:
    /html: statichtml
    /images: staticimages
```